# ActiveMQ scheduler's store in JDBC

Tags: jdbc, activemq-classic, scheduler, failover

My intent is to configure the ActiveMQ 5.14.5 scheduler to use JDBC.
I have already included following in the `activemq.xml`

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="activemq-data" schedulerDirectory="scheduler-data" schedulerSupport="true">
   <persistenceAdapter>
      <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="scheduler-data" dataSource="#oracle-ds" useDatabaseLock="false"/>
   </persistenceAdapter>
   ...
```

However the scheduler still persists into local KahaDB.

Comment: For what it's worth a message broker is not the ideal place to implement a scheduler. You might be better of using a dedicated scheduler like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It can use JDBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Scheduler Store implementation written for a JDBC data source, the current implementation is built on top of the KahaDB data store model.  The SchedulerStore API was created such that a user could write and contribute a JDBC implementation if they wanted to but so far the community hasn't seen any drive to do so which means you are limited to the KahaDB version unless you'd like to contribute a JDBC variant.